# dynamic text boxes through javascript

Tags: javascript

i have created textboxes dynamically in javascript it works fine. But the problem is that the textboxes is creating in blank page the below is my java script code

```
function testt(a){
d
for(var k=0; k<a; k++){
document.write("<br />");   

}}
function test()
{

for(var i=0; i<5; i++)
{

document.write("<input type='text' name=''>");

}
}
```

pleaze help me some one

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/802943

Comment: Where you writing the text fields to? Or are you putting this script within your document `<body />`?

Comment: no i am writing in head tag

Comment: what will be the solution con you exlain me

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Why write to head?

Comment: i want to show these textbox in the same page

Comment: Your problem is: Where on this page do you need to show them?

Comment: in any area but it should not overwrite the previous content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To append textboxes you can use this code, you need to attach jQuery library, this is the easiest way.

```
<head>
<script>
function giveTextBox(a){
for(var k=0; k<a; k++){
    $('.container').append('<input type="text" name=""/><br/>');
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p class="container"> </p>
</body>
```

This should help.